# How to calculate Frequency with Fast Fourier Transformation

Tags: c++, arduino, fft

i am working on a pulse sensor project. I get data from the sensor like this:
[image: voltage without artifacts]

Now i would like to use this code:

```
  #include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

const double PI = 3.141592653589793238460;

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

// Cooley–Tukey FFT (in-place, divide-and-conquer)
// Higher memory requirements and redundancy although more intuitive
void fft(CArray& x)
{
    const size_t N = x.size();
    if (N <= 1) return;

    // divide
    CArray even = x[std::slice(0, N/2, 2)];
    CArray  odd = x[std::slice(1, N/2, 2)];

    // conquer
    fft(even);
    fft(odd);

    // combine
    for (size_t k = 0; k < N/2; ++k)
    {
        Complex t = std::polar(1.0, -2 * PI * k / N) * odd[k];
        x[k    ] = even[k] + t;
        x[k+N/2] = even[k] - t;
    }
}

// Cooley-Tukey FFT (in-place, breadth-first, decimation-in-frequency)
// Better optimized but less intuitive
// !!! Warning : in some cases this code make result different from not optimased version above (need to fix bug)
// The bug is now fixed @2017/05/30 
void fft(CArray &x)
{
    // DFT
    unsigned int N = x.size(), k = N, n;
    double thetaT = 3.14159265358979323846264338328L / N;
    Complex phiT = Complex(cos(thetaT), -sin(thetaT)), T;
    while (k > 1)
    {
        n = k;
        k >>= 1;
        phiT = phiT * phiT;
        T = 1.0L;
        for (unsigned int l = 0; l < k; l++)
        {
            for (unsigned int a = l; a < N; a += n)
            {
                unsigned int b = a + k;
                Complex t = x[a] - x[b];
                x[a] += x[b];
                x[b] = t * T;
            }
            T *= phiT;
        }
    }
    // Decimate
    unsigned int m = (unsigned int)log2(N);
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < N; a++)
    {
        unsigned int b = a;
        // Reverse bits
        b = (((b & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((b & 0x55555555) << 1));
        b = (((b & 0xcccccccc) >> 2) | ((b & 0x33333333) << 2));
        b = (((b & 0xf0f0f0f0) >> 4) | ((b & 0x0f0f0f0f) << 4));
        b = (((b & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((b & 0x00ff00ff) << 8));
        b = ((b >> 16) | (b << 16)) >> (32 - m);
        if (b > a)
        {
            Complex t = x[a];
            x[a] = x[b];
            x[b] = t;
        }
    }
    //// Normalize (This section make it not working correctly)
    //Complex f = 1.0 / sqrt(N);
    //for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    //  x[i] *= f;
}


int main()
{
    const Complex test[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
    CArray data(test, 8);

    // forward fft
    fft(data);

    std::cout << "fft" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

To calculate the frequency of my heartbeat. The problem i have right now is making sense of the output i get:
fft
(4,0)
(1,-2.41421)
(0,0)
(1,-0.414214)
(0,0)
(1,0.414214)
(0,0)
(1,2.41421)

What is this? I think it is the Amplitude and the phase, but i dont know how to calculate from that the frequency.

The frequency of a pulse is around 0.33 Hz to 3 Hz. Is the resolution of this code good enough? I never had to work with fourier transformation

Thanks for the help. I look forward to your answers.

Comment: How could this possibly compile as C code?

Comment: Refer to ARM CMSIS library.

Comment: @tilz0R More specifically, CMSIS-DSP.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Actually the frequency increases with increasing index. Index 1 is for the sampling frequency divided by `N` (where `N` is the number of FFT input points), index 2 for twice the frequency as that at index 1, etc.

Comment: @SleuthEye: Thanks, fixed, and moved to an answer.

Comment: @vandench i got this code from a website. nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @Xenoshell it doesn’t matter where you got it, tag it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex numbers that are outputs of the FFT are the coefficients that the component sine waves are multiplied by. Essentially they are rectangular coordinates, and the equivalent polar coordinates of magnitude and angle would give you the amplitude and phase.

The frequency is determined by position in the array. The element at index *i* is for the sampling frequency multiplied by *i*/*N*, where *N* is the number of elements in the FFT.

Comment: so for this example the groundwave is (4,0). With that being said the frequency of this element is 4/8 = 0.5 Hz. Right?

Comment: @Xenoshell: (4, 0) is the element at index 0, so it is the coefficient for frequency 0 (the “DC” component).

Comment: @Xenoshell: The element at index 1 ((1,-2.41421) in your example) is for 1/N times the sampling frequency (1/8 times the sampling frequency in your example). It is not 1/8 Hz unless the sampling frequency is 1 Hz, and the element at index 4 is not for .5 Hz unless the sampling frequency is 1 Hz. For example, if a sensor takes a measurement 80,000 times per second, the sampling frequency is 80 kHz. If you take an FFT of 1024 consecutive samples, the output element at index 1 is for frequency 80 kHz • 1/1024 = 78.125 Hz. The element at index 2 is for 156.25 Hz.